# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 but error resources are inside built framework

Tags: objective-c, xcode, undefined-symbol

I start develop iOS app using framework code I built myself from source code.

I added needed architectures to framework project and built framework, that add it to my application.
And when I tried to build application, `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64` errors was appeared, eg:

```
"_AES_ige_encrypt", referenced from:
  _MTAesEncryptInplace in MTProtoKit iOS (MTEncryption.o)
  _MTAesEncryptInplaceAndModifyIv in MTProtoKit iOS (MTEncryption.o)
  ...
"_AES_set_encrypt_key", referenced from:
  _MTAesEncryptInplace in MTProtoKit iOS (MTEncryption.o)
  _MTAesEncryptInplaceAndModifyIv in MTProtoKit iOS (MTEncryption.o)
  ...
```

And many others, not only at `MTEncryption`

I looked framework source, file `MTEncryption.m`:

```
void MTAesEncryptInplace(NSMutableData *data, NSData *key, NSData *iv)
{
    AES_KEY aesKey;
    AES_set_encrypt_key(key.bytes, 256, &aesKey); // <-- _AES_set_encrypt_key
    unsigned char aesIv[AES_BLOCK_SIZE * 2];
    memcpy(aesIv, iv.bytes, iv.length);

    AES_ige_encrypt(data.bytes, (void *)data.bytes, data.length, &aesKey, aesIv, true); // <-- _AES_ige_encrypt
}
```

These methods are in `.../openssl/aes.h` that is already included to build phases.

But I noticed that `aes.m` file is missing (not just missing in build phases but file doesn't exist).
Is it normal? Or exactly `.m` files missing is build failing reason? But if it's the reason, how framework was built successfully?

Answer (score 1):

From scouting around the simulator files, i can't see a definitive iteration of aes or openssl which come "part and parcel".

On that note, you'd have to compile your own OpenSSL to support these missing libraries.

I did find a github repo for you that could be of help:

https://github.com/x2on/OpenSSL-for-iPhone

Hope this helps..

Comment: I got different version of that framework from another source, and my problem was solved. But thank you, I voted up your answer for possibly useful advice!